# How to change SDK state for Chirp in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, chirp

I tried changing it manually,

```
 if chirp.state == CHIRP_SDK_STATE_RUNNING {
        chirp.state = CHIRP_SDK_STATE_STOPPED
    }
```

but the error reads it is a get only property.

Comment: Please read the docs of the tools you are using.  https://docs.chirp.io/ios/Classes/ChirpSDK.html#/c:objc(cs)ChirpSDK(im)stop - it takes 5 minutes to find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the state of the ChirpSDK. To stop the SDK you need to call the `stop` method. Then the state will change to `CHIRP_SDK_STATE_STOPPED`.